# Probability in a lottery-game

Tags: probability

Let's say that we are playing a game, say Joker. A socalled Joker-number has a seven digit number, where every digit is one of the numbers, $0, 1,\dots, 9$.

When playing Joker, you have a number that should be as close to the Joker-number as possible: the "right digit" is defined as the number of digits from right to left, which in an unbroken order must agree with the Joker-number.

For example: If the Joker-number is $1234567$, and we have the number $6494567$, then there are four right digits (the first four digits from right agree, while there is a difference on the fifth digit). If you have $1234569$, you have no right (the first digit number from right is wrong, so the rest don't mean anything). If you have the number $4134587$, you have only one right digit.

Now imagine that a player of the Joker game has the number $6494567$ (the specific number is actually irrelevant in this case), and that the Joker-number is drawn by random.

Let the stochastic variable $X$ denote the number of right digits you obtain, which is the values $0,1\dots, 7$.

a) Determine the mean $EX$

**My answer**: First we need to determine $P(X=0),\dots, P(X=7)$. We'll use that $$P(X=k)=\left ( \frac{1}{10} \right )^{k}\left ( 1-\frac{1}{10} \right )^{7-k} \tag{1}$$ where $k\in \{0,1,\dots, 7\}$. So we have $EX=\sum_{k=0}^{7}kP(X=k)$.

b) What is the probability that the player at least has 2 right digits?

**My answer:** I'll use the formula $(1)$ to insert this
$$P(X\geq 2) = 1 - (P(X=0) + P(X=1)).$$

Now imagine that the player is playing the Joker game three weeks in a row: the player has the same number $6494567$ in all three weeks, and for each week there is drawn a new Joker-number by random.

c) What is the probabilty that the player has at least 2 right digits exactly one time during those three weeks?

**My answer:** I'll take the value from b). The probability would then be
$$\binom{3}{1}P(X\geq 2)^1 (1-P(X\geq 2))^{3-1}.$$

Comment: Okay, what are you asking for? I checked your answer until c) Are you sure  $$\binom{3}{1}P(X\geq 2)^1 (1-P(X\geq 2))^{3-1}.$$ is actually the probability that the player has at least 2 right digits exactly one time during thoses three week?

Comment: @Marine1 That's the way I understood the question. I'm actually not sure which is why I'm asking if my answers are correct.

Comment: no it's okay, I don't see any problem with such a value...

Comment: according to your formula $P(X=0)=\left(\frac9{10}\right)^7$. Should this not be $P(X=0)=\frac9{10}$? (probability that utmost right number is not the same as utmost right of Joker-number)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) Approach for finding mean:

Let $X_{n}$ denote the number of right digits when we are working
with a Joker-number that has $n$ digits and let $\mu_{n}$ denote
its mean. So you are actually trying to find $\mu_{7}$.

Let $E$ be the event that the first digit number from the right side
is correct. Then: $$\mu_{n}=\mathbb{E}\left(X_{n}\mid E\right)P\left(E\right)+\mathbb{E}\left(X_{n}\mid E^{c}\right)P\left(E^{c}\right)=\left(1+\mu_{n-1}\right).\frac{1}{10}+0.\frac{9}{10}=\frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{10}\mu_{n-1}$$

This leads to: $$\mu_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{10}\right)^{k}=\frac{1}{9}\left(1-\left(\frac{1}{10}\right)^{n}\right)$$

Comment: I found another solution and got the same result as yours. I'll accept this answer since you were the only one who helped me this.